# Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Viewport missing in WP8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, xna, windows-phone

I finally upgraded my WP7 app to WP8. Everything worked fine and the process was smooth. Unfortunately, it seems like the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Viewport namespace cannot be found anymore.

> The type or namespace name 'Viewport' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to resolve this issue, as I need this viewport stuff in my augmented reality app to define the final monitor image...

Any ideas? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `Viewport` class available in Windows Phone 8. But there was the same problemn for [GART toolkit](http://gart.codeplex.com/), and it was solved by implementing own Viewport class.

Being your app an Augmented Reality app too, I think their solution will be valid for you too. You can get the source code here:

http://gart.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GeoARToolkit/NonXnaUtils/Viewport.cs

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint. Moreover, the developers behind the GART toolkit really helped me to successfully upgrade my project.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has deprecated the XNA Framework in Windows Phone 8. Some XNA assemblies can still be referenced but not `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.dll`.

Here is the list of assemblies that can still be referenced:

> Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.dll 
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServicesExtensions.dll
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch.dll
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.dll
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.MediaLibraryExtensions.dll

For more information, check out the [MSDN page on this topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207003%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Olivier Payen. But what can I do instead to resolve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: What do you use the Viewport for? MonoGame is one possibility http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/XNA_Games_On_Windows_Phone_8_with_Monogame